# Why I can't call using the Uri class?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, phone-call

I am using following code to make call from my android code .But it doesn't seem to work .All this code does is to display phone number in call application but it doesn't call.

```
Uri call=Uri.parse("tel:9008765750");//that's an example phone number
Intent ii= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,call);
startActivity(ii);
```

Comment: instead of Intent.ACTION_VIEW use Intent.ACTION_CALL and make sure you declare the permission in manifest ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Permission in Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Thank you Pal,That is all I need to call .

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Intent ii= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,call);
```

to

```
Intent ii= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,call);
```

and add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

`Intent.ACTION_VIEW` is used to `Display the data to the user.`

So when you use `tel:` with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` it will just display the number.

`Intent.ACTION_CALL` is used to `Perform a call to someone specified by the data.`

Answer (score 0):

do u have declare `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` in manifest.xml?

Comment: Thank you that was all I need .Along with Intent.ACTION_CALL . Thank you!